# `$group` by unique items in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say we have documents like

```
[
 {tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
 {tags: ['b', 'c', 'd']}
]
```

How would we then count the documents per tag, so

```
[
 {_id: 'a', count: 1},
 {_id: 'b', count: 2},
 {_id: 'c', count: 2},
 {_id: 'd', count: 1}
]
```

Because doing a normal `$group` on `$tags` will (of course) give a different result.

Comment: You should be able to do a `$unwind` on the `tags` field first, then do the `$group` on the same key and `{ $sum: 1 }` to get the count.

Comment: @chridam Ah, of course, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following query will get you the results. `$unwind` is the key here.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$tags" }, 
       { $group : { _id :  "$tags", total : { $sum : 1 } } }] )
```

For reference - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/